Micronaut repository returns only one result in Page even though there are more
I'm doing a simple select query using Micronaut Data v4.4.0 like so:
myRepository.findAll(specification, Pageable.from(0, 10));

My repo is:
  @JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.ANSI)
  public interface RequestRepository extends CrudRepository<Request, String> 
  {
    Page<Request> findAll(PredicateSpecification<Request> specification, Pageable page);
  }

I put a breakpoint, and I can see that though the size is 10, the size of content is still 1 instead of 10

I tried the same with a PageableRepository as well but the result is the same.
Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a Micronaut bug?

How sure are you there are more based on the given specification?

totalSize is 89503, as shown by the screenshot of the DefaultPage object. A SQL query confirmed it as well.

TL;DR
If we follow the docs for CriteriaSpecifications, your repository interface should look like this:
public interface RequestRepository extends PageableRepository<Request, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Request>

Interface method Page<Request> findAll(PredicateSpecification<Request> specification, Pageable page) is defined in interface JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> and can be removed from interface RequestRepository.

To verify the above code, we can use the following guide as base:
https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-data-jdbc-repository-maven-java.html
Add the following to the POM:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

Change GenreRepository to this:
package example.micronaut;

import example.micronaut.domain.Genre;
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.NonNull;
import io.micronaut.data.annotation.Id;
import io.micronaut.data.exceptions.DataAccessException;
import io.micronaut.data.jdbc.annotation.JdbcRepository;
import io.micronaut.data.model.query.builder.sql.Dialect;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.PageableRepository;

import io.micronaut.data.repository.jpa.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import io.micronaut.data.repository.jpa.criteria.PredicateSpecification;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.MYSQL)
// ADDED JpaSpecificationExecutor<Genre>
public interface GenreRepository extends PageableRepository<Genre, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Genre> {

    Genre save(@NonNull @NotBlank String name);

    @Transactional
    default Genre saveWithException(@NonNull @NotBlank String name) {
        save(name);
        throw new DataAccessException("test exception");
    }

    long update(@NonNull @NotNull @Id Long id, @NonNull @NotBlank String name);

    // ADDED class Specifications
    class Specifications {
        static PredicateSpecification<Genre> nameStartsWith(String prefix) {
            return (root, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), prefix + "%");
        }
    }
}

And finally the tests to prove that paging works along with criteria
package example.micronaut;

import io.micronaut.data.model.Pageable;
import io.micronaut.test.extensions.junit5.annotation.MicronautTest;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static example.micronaut.GenreRepository.Specifications.nameStartsWith;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@MicronautTest
class GenreRepositoryTest {

    @Inject
    GenreRepository sut;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        sut.deleteAll();
        Stream.of("Bob", "Billy", "Alice")
                .forEach(name -> sut.save(name));
    }

    @Test
    void given_three_names_expect_page_with_two_records() {
        // assert that there are 3 records in db
        assertEquals(3, sut.count());

        // find all records where name starts with "B"
        var nameStartsWithBResult = sut.findAll(
                nameStartsWith("B"), Pageable.from(0, 10));

        // assert total size
        assertEquals(2, nameStartsWithBResult.getTotalSize());

        // assert that we have two records
        assertEquals(2, nameStartsWithBResult.getContent().size());
    }
}


There was no GenreRepository in my question. Looks like an accidental copy paste.
Adding the JpaSpecificationExecutor to my repository did not fix the issue.

Hi @ritratt. As I wrote in my answer; it was code from a guide. If you add code for your PredicateSpecification and class Request to your question, I can update my answer. BR
